# How to inactive the Tabs in Richfaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using jsf with Richfaces. I've created a tabpanel using `<rich:tabpanel>`. I have taken 4 tabs like *tab1*, *tab2*, *tab3* and *tab4*. if I run the application *tab1* is default one. If I go to next tab I use navigation for every tab like `NEXT<<` and `PREV>>` .

1. If I click on a tab label, it is also changing the tabs. if I run the application, I want *tab1* to be active and all others tabs are disabled (like *tab2* or *tab3* are disabled. If I click navigation buttons, only the tabs will be active.)
2. If I run the application, the *tab1* will be active after fill up the *tab1* details click the `NEXT<<` navigation then *tab2* is active. Now the *tab1* and *tab2* are active. *tab3* and *tab4* are inactives.

What are the solution for the above two questions?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax">
        <rich:tab label="First">
            Here is tab #1
        </rich:tab>
        <rich:tab label="Second" disabled="true">
            Here is tab #2
        </rich:tab>
        <rich:tab label="Third" disabled="true">
            Here is tab #3
        </rich:tab>
    </rich:tabPanel>
```

here second and third tab will be disabled , you can do something like

```
disabled= #{Bean.isDisabledTab1}
```

And handel it on next ,previous

Answer (score 0):

Complementing org.life.java answer, you can add an action listener to the button or link that you are clicking when you switch tabs, for example:

```
                <a4j:commandLink id="identifierLink" value="#{bean.ID_COUNT}"
                actionListener="#{bean.switchTab}" reRender="clientTabPanel, clientTable">
                    <f:param  id="internalID" value="#{bean.INTERNAL_ID}" name="internalIDParam"/>
            </a4j:commandLink>
```

The switchTab action listener method would contain the logic to enable or disable the other tabs (just like org.life.java mentioned), and you could use f:param in case you want to pass something to your action listener when deciding to switch or not. I think you need to re-Render the tabPanel when you update the related property for the "disabled" attribute.